# Number of events is not always accurate when rolling up rep by post

Tags: bug, reputation, reputation-history

Today I hit my rep cap and noticed an odd sum of events for a particular question. Seems like a completely inconsequential off-by-one problem perhaps, and I have seen it before but I think only on days when I've hit my rep cap

[image]

(In this case I posted the question after I had already hit my rep, so *all* events relating to the question did not contribute to my rep - maybe that is a factor, I'm not sure.)

Surely this isn't by design, but I think it's completely inconsequential, and it does fix itself (between the time I started formulating this answer and now, it has self-corrected). I just wanted to bring it up in case the devs are in that part of the code for other, more important reasons, and want to take a look at this at the same time.

Similar situation:
[image]

Comment: Might have something to do with the unread part. The yellow signifies new changes. Perhaps it was trying to notify you that you had 4 *new* reputation events. That doesn't really explain why the fifth one got included in that list though. It'd normally separate it into a list of 4 and then one separate event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The individual upvote list is loaded asynchronously via AJAX.

Combine that with caching and I can see scenarios where one webserver serving the main page has a different number of events, cached before the last upvote came in, and the webserver generating the AJAX response with the list of upvotes did 'see' the extra upvote.

This is almost unavoidable in modern scalable websites; asynchronous responses sometimes are out of sync. Would I be presumptuous to call this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)?

As such, I bet you can't reproduce that discrepancy now, however hard you try. :-)

Comment: I believe this, but it seems funny that "4 events" was loaded completely separately from the list of events. That sounds like a wasted call to me, since if you have the relevant list, you can derive a count. Oh well.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Is it possible that you loaded your reputation history page, and then left it sit for 7 minutes before expanding that specific post? It could be that you *had* 4 new events and that the next event also being 3 minutes ago was just a coincidence. The time piece next to the post doesn't update when you expand it to retrieve the event list for the post.

Comment: @animuson no, I don't sit on the rep page for that long.