# Reputation is shown wrongly

Tags: discussion, reputation

In meta stackoverflow my reputation is shown wrongly. Why it is so? Is it a Bug?

[image]

Comment: No repro here..

Comment: Ohh Yes. Now its perfect. Then why did that happened?

Comment: Caching. It's always caching.

Comment: This is a dupe; the data per post is fetched with AJAX and thus calculated at a different time than the overall post. Thus, the overall page can get out of date.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Number of events is not always accurate when rolling up rep by post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138574/number-of-events-is-not-always-accurate-when-rolling-up-rep-by-post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were only two events in the time of page load.

When you click the arrow, AJAX request is sent to fetch the events, so when you clicked there were already four events.